# Django Angular Facebook authentication

Tags: django, angularjs, facebook-authentication

I want to do a very simple web app where you can log-in using your facebook account.

I am very comfortable  with the `django` framework and also `angularjs`. I have an idea how to integrate these two using `tastypie` api framework for django.

So if I am correct django's backend would be throwing some JSON which can be used by angularjs and so on.

Where I am confused is the authentication mechanism with facebook.
How do I integrate the Facebook's authentication with my app ?
What  would be a good design for such an app ?

I am not expecting a complete design or architecture for my app from anyone , but some direction so that I can go forward with the app .

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a small article on this subject as it seems it was not clearly explained anywhere. I found it easily done with django-rest-framework instead of tastypie though.

Here are the main steps used to authenticate (I’ll try to add a little schema to illustrate) :

1. On the angular side, user authenticate on facebook with Oauth.io API (it could be directly with Facebook js API).
2. Client gets a Facebook authentication token.
3. FB token is used to ask for authentication on server side.
4. python-social-auth authenticate with FB with the given token.
5. django-rest-framework sends back to client a auth token for REST API calls.
6. Angular client passes the token in headers when making API calls.

You can find my article here [about facebook angularjs auth with a django rest backend](http://blog.wizer.fr/2013/11/angularjs-facebook-with-a-django-rest-api/)

Comment: When I click on link it shows This site can’t be reached

Answer (score 1):

This repo is designed with php on authenticate server side but it has all of the facebook login code you would need for angular. It should give you an overall idea of how to get started:

https://github.com/Terumi/AngularJS-Facebook-Login